# custom js file loading before jquery loads in asset pipeline

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I am trying to include a separate javascript file to only load on one page in my rails app.

I added a

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "jumpstart" %>
```

At the bottom of the page (the page that needs this file).

Unfortunately, my jquery library is loading AFTER my js file loads, so my '$' is undefined.

It looks something like this

- HTML/CSS for the page Custom
- JS file for that page
- REST OF ASSET PIPELINE (this is where the jquery library is being loaded)

Does anyone know a workaround on how I can get the jquery library to load before this custom js file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `content_for`.

In your layout, **after** `javascript_include_tag 'application`:

```
<%= yield :scripts%>
```

In your page:

```
<% content_for :scripts do %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag "jumpstart" %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Sorry, I am a little confused. I only have <%= javascript_include_tag "jumpstart" %>
in my jumpstart.html.erb file all the way at the bottom.  Where would I put the <%= yield :scripts %>? I guess in your description I am confused on the location of Layout and Page. Where is the layout you are referencing, where is the page? (I assume the jumpstart.html.erb page) Thanks for all the help!

Comment: Layout is application.html.erb